# Netty setting and handling connection

Tags: java, netty

I'm not sure if I'm setting right bootstrap for my needs.

As far I have this(i.e. for 2 clients):

**Server display only this:**

REGISTER

Complete

Added 1 player

[Server] - /127.0.0.1:51850 has joined!

Players online: 1

REGISTER

Complete

Added 2 player

[Server] - /127.0.0.1:51869 has joined!

Players online: 2

**When it should display also "Alo..." from each client**

Client display data from Server *only if* next client connect(cards are setting in other function and build correctly). On first(if is only 1 client)/last client display nothing. **I want to display on each client immediately cards when client is connected isntead of waiting for next client.**

Setting Server:

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
                    bootstrap.group(bossGroup,workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChatServerInitializer())
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);

                    ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
                     f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            // bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }
        finally { 
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

ChatServerInitializer:

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel arg0) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = arg0.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ChatServerHandler());
    }
}
```

ChatServerHandler:

```
static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

private String cards = "";

    @Override
    public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
            super.channelRegistered(ctx);
                System.out.println("REGISTER");
        }
    @Override
    public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception{
        Channel incoming = ctx.channel();

        final ChannelFuture f = incoming.writeAndFlush(cards);
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
               System.out.println("Complete");
            }
        });

        for(Channel channel : channels) {
            channel.writeAndFlush("[Server] - " + incoming.remoteAddress() + " has joined!\n");

        }

        channels.add(ctx.channel());
        showMessage( "[Server] - " + incoming.remoteAddress().toString() + " has joined!" );
        showMessage( "Players online: " + channels.size() );
        System.out.println("Added " + channels.size() + " player");
    }

    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Channel incoming = ctx.channel();
        for(Channel channel : channels) {
            channel.writeAndFlush("[Server] - " + incoming.remoteAddress() + " has left!\n");
        }
        showMessage( "[Server] - " + incoming.remoteAddress().toString() + " has left!" );
        channels.remove(ctx.channel());
        showMessage( "Players online: " + channels.size() );

    }
    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String arg1) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(arg1);
    }

    }
```

Setting Client:

```
EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try{
            Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
                    .group(group)
                    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                    .option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
                    .handler(new ChatClientInitializer());
        //  bootstrap.connect(host,port).sync().channel();
            ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync();
            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }
        finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
```

ChatClientInitializer:

```
@Override
    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel arg0) throws Exception {

        ChannelPipeline pipeline = arg0.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8192, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());

        pipeline.addLast("handler", new ChatClientHandler());
    }
```

ChatClientHandler:

```
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx){
        final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush("Alo...");
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
               System.out.println("Completed..");
            }
        });
    }

    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, String arg1) throws Exception{
            System.out.println(arg1);
            showMessage(arg1);
    }
```

What I finnaly want is:
Connect 8 Clients to Server. Each Client should get from the Server, the same 5 cards(deck) and for each 2 diffrent cards(hand). Like in texas holdem. And then Server should listen if Clients bet/check/fold and interact with each respond.
Is that bootstrap setting good? Should I do all this code in Client/Server Handler?

Comment: take a look at `ChannelGroups`: http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html . I would suggest adding the clients to a group in `channelActive()` and removing them in `channelInactive()`. This way you can broadcast a deck of cards. After that you can do all the work in the `channelRead0()` methods. You would have to transport some sort of token to the clients so they know whose turn it is.

Comment: I'm adding/removing clients in ChatServerHandler, but question is why when first client connect there is no message received from server, its apper only if next client connect and so on... And server doesn't received messaage from Client only information if Client connect/disconnect

Comment: the first one doesn't receive a message because you broadcast before you add the new channel to the group.

Comment: Ok the answer for not reciving was that i didnt flush from client/server with \r\n